# Quotient of a category by a free group action

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let Cat denote the 1-category of small categories.  The functor Mor : Cat -> Set which assigns to a category its set of morphisms (aka Hom([• -> •], -)) does not commute with most colimits.  Does it commute with quotients by free group actions?  In other words, if C is a small category and G is a group acting on C such that the action of G on the objects of C is free, does Mor(C/G) = (Mor C)/G?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found a "high-tech" argument which is maybe more convincing.

The external input to the argument is that if X -> Z <- Y is a diagram of G-sets with G acting freely on Z (and hence on X and Y) then (X x<sub>Z</sub> Y)/G = (X/G) x<sub>(Z/G)</sub> (Y/G).  This is pretty clear because we can always write our original X -> Z <- Y in the form (X/G) x G -> (Z/G) x G <- (Y/G) x G.

Now we use the presentation of Cat as the localization of the category of simplicial sets in which the local objects are the simplicial sets X such that X<sub>n</sub> -> X<sub>1</sub> x<sub>X<sub>0</sub></sub> ... x<sub>X<sub>0</sub></sub> X<sub>1</sub> is an isomorphism for all n >= 2.  By general nonsense about localizations, if C is a category (viewed as a simplicial set) with a G-action, we can compute the colimit C/G by taking the colimit levelwise and then localizing the resulting object.  But the levelwise quotient is already local, by our previous observation.  Since C<sub>1</sub> represents the set of morphisms of C, we're done.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is yes, provided your action has the following data that you didn't specify:

- For any g in G and any f: a -> b, an assignment gf: ga -> gb, in a way that strictly respects multiplication in G (including 1f = f).

If you don't say what G does on morphisms, I don't see how the question makes sense.

Comment: You're right, I meant to say that G acts on C as an object of Cat.  Hopefully the new wording is better.

That was the answer I expected, but why is it true?

Comment: I guess the short answer would be that the set of all morphisms is a disjoint union of morphism sets between pairs of objects (this is often an explicit axiom in the definition of category), so the freeness of the G-action on objects translates to a free action on morphisms.  I may be missing something - are there subtleties in your definition of quotient category C/G?

Comment: I was defining C/G as the colimit of the diagram BG -> Cat given by the G-object C (where BG is the groupoid with one object which has automorphism group G).  Usually when forming a colimit in Cat we have to throw in some compositions of morphisms (e.g. consider the quotient [• -> •] / [• ∐ •] which has infinitely many morphisms).  But now you've convinced me that in my case I can just write down a category with objects (Ob C)/G and morphisms (Mor C)/G and check the universal property (functors out of it correspond to G-invariant functors from C).

Answer (score 2):

This came up in something I'm working on, and this question was the first hit on google.

It seems to me that this has nothing to do with G acting freely, and that the answer is always yes.  One can always define a quotient category C/G with objects (Ob C)/G and morphisms (Mor C)/G, with composition and identities defined in a more-or-less obvious manner (use the action of G to match up two arrows $f: C\to D$ and $h: gD\to E$ whose domains are equal in C/G, and then compose; note that $h\circ g(f)$ and $g^{-1} (h) \circ f$ are equivalent morphisms in the quotient).  I was a little surprised that this makes sense, but it seems to.

I think it is elementary to check that C/G satisfies the universal property defining the colimit of the functor $BG \to$ Cat.

Am I missing something?  Edit: YES!  See the comments below.  If you care to see what I was actually thinking about (a version of this which is actually correct) look at my answer to  [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22686/quotient-of-a-category-by-a-group-action/22760#22760) subsequent question.

Comment: What if I take C = BH, where H is a group with an action of G?  I think the quotient category will be B(H with the relations x = gx for all x in H imposed), whose set of morphisms will be different from the set of orbits for the action of G on H as a set.

Comment: If the action is not free on objects, you have choices when picking the $g$ which makes the morphisms "match up".

Comment: Ah, I see.  I think this saved me from a fair amount of time-wasting.  I'll leave the answer up, as a warning...