# Quotient of a category by a group action

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let a group $G$ act on a small category $C$. If $G$ acts freely on objects, there is a sensible construction of the quotient $C/G$ (this is briefly spelt out [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/636/quotient-of-a-category-by-a-free-group-action/22682#22682))

What about the non-free case?

Comment: The appropriate 2-categorical construction is to replace $C$ by $C \times EG$ where $EG$ is the codiscrete category ($\mathrm{Hom}(x, y) = *$ for all $x$ and $y$) with object set $G$ and $G$ acting by left translation, and forming the quotient $(C \times EG)/G$ as described there.  But, I guess your question is about the 1-categorical colimit?

Comment: Indeed. Do you have a reference for the 2-categorical construction, anyways?

Answer (score 4):

From the view point of representations of finite dimensional algebras, there is a construction called the "orbit category" or "skew category" construction. The construction appears, for example, [a paper by Cibils and Marcos](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0312214), [a paper by Keller](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0503240), and [a paper by Asashiba](http://arxiv.org/abs/0807.4706).

If you browse these papers, you will notice that their construction is a version of the Grothendieck construction. Here we regard an action of a group $G$ on a category $C$ as a functor
$$G \longrightarrow Cats.$$

So it's related to Reid's comment.

Comment: Thomason's thesis says that for any diagram `$F:D\to Cat$`, the Grothendieck wreath product of D by F (or F by D?) is a model for the homotopy colimit, in the sense that its geometric realization is homotopy colimit of the geometric realization of the diagram. So I guess that's what's going on here (hence the relationship with Reid's comment).

Comment: Yes. That’s exactly what I wanted to say in the last sentence.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a particular special case that seems to be useful to me:

Let $F: D \to G$-Sets be a diagram of $G$-sets, indexed by some small category D.  Then ignoring the G-actions, one can form the Grothendieck wreath product $D\wr F$.  Objects are pairs (d, x) with $x\in F(d)$, and morphisms $(d,x)\to (d', x')$ are arrows $a:d\to d'$ such that $F(a)(x) = x'$.  This category inherits an action of G from the actions on the sets in the diagram; $g\cdot (d,x) = (d, gx)$ (on morphisms, $g$ looks like the identity: $g\cdot (a:(d,x)\to(d',x')) = a:(d,gx)\to(d',gx')$, which makes since $F(a)$ is $G$-equivariant.

There is another diagram $F/G : D\to$ Sets, which takes $d\in D$ to $F(D)/G$, and there's a natural functor $D\wr F \to D\wr (F/G)$.  I claim that this functor satisfies the universal property of the colimit, i.e. $(D\wr F)/G = D\wr (F/G)$.

This special case has the interesting property that the nerve of $D\wr (F/G)$ is precisely $N_\cdot (D\wr F)/G$.  I don't think that will hold for arbitrary group actions on categories.